# Constructor for `const` object

Tags: c++, constructor, arguments, constants

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

class test
{
public:
    test( char *arg )
    :   _arg( arg )
    {}  
    char *_arg;
};

int main( )
{
    char *txt1       = "Text one";  // Ignore this warning.
    const char *txt2 = "Text two";

    test       t1( txt1 );  // Normal case, nothing new.
    const test t2( txt2 );  // Since object is const, I'd like to be able to pass a const argument in.
}
```

It blows up with the error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
   const test t2( txt2 );
```

Then I tried to add a second constructor to test whether the compiler could select the right one for `t2`, my `const` object:

```
    test( const char *arg )
    :   _arg( arg )
    {}
```

but then the error is:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
  : _arg( arg )
```

So declaring my object as `const` does not make its fields `const` as well.

How to properly declare my class constructors so that it can handle `const` and non-const object creation?

Comment: Inside `test`, do you want to reference characters that you can modify or read-only characters?

Comment: In the former case, always copy it. Like how `std::string` works.

Comment: (note that a non-const pointer can be cast to a const pointer, so if you (or your struct) have a const pointer that you (or your struct) doesn't own, don't expect it to stay unchanged forever)

Comment: Thanks for your question @nwp. Actually this test used `char*` but not my real usage case. This is just a simplification. My `const` object will not change anything. Only `const` member functions will be called. For my `non-const` object, I can do anything.

Comment: in class `test`, `_arg` needs to be `const char *` as well. Then it will work. Your problem has nothing to do with t1 or t2 being const or not. It about the `chars´ your pointer points to

Comment: Main question is - why would You need such behaviour? It does not seem useful

Comment: @j4x The error is there for a reason and it points out to a possible design issue. You want to use original pointer if it's modifiable, and copy contents if not, but this leads to another problem. Who and under what circumstances is the owner of the string, and how to store this information.

Comment: const-qualification of objects doesn't apply until the constructor completes: otherwise the constructor wouldn't be able to initialize data members (they'd be `const`!).

Comment: @bartop, to explain why I do need this this question would become really verbose. I tried to simplify it as much as possible so please give me your trust and believe me that there might be a use for it.

Comment: _"// Ignore this warning._" No

Comment: @luk32 I think you misunderstood me. I don't want an automatic "copy-if-cost" but simply I need to use my class `const` methods on a const object created from a const argument. No copies, no data modification.

Comment: `const char *` is not the "const argument version" of `char *`. That's `char * const` which is a different type. If you can say specifically what you want to _do_ with your class, and how it should manage memory, we might be able to help you.

Comment: @j4x Yes, I misread  user202729 comment as yours, but for the answer I wrote, I think got your point.

Comment: `char txt1[] = "Text one";` so you don't have the warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to properly declare my class constructors so that it can handle const and non-const object creation?

The object isn't `const` *during* construction, or the constructor wouldn't be able to initialize the object (since all data members would be `const`).

So, constructors can't be const-qualified and you can't have a constructor overload used for `const` objects.

Now, you *can* overload on the argument, but your data member always has type `char *` during construction, although it's qualified to `char * const` (*not* `const char *`) when used in a const-qualified instance of test.

Options are:

1. overload constructor on argument type, and store a `char *` *always*. If you're passed a `const char *` you have to copy it (and you're responsible for knowing that you own and must deallocate this memory)

   In this scheme, you rely on keeping the pointer private and using const-qualified accessors to stop the contents of the pointer being changed via a const-qualified object.

   Again, you need to do this manually because `char * const` is a different type than `const char *`, because constness of the pointed-to type isn't related to constness of the pointer: having a const instance of your class just stops you mutating the pointer, not the characters it points to.
2. overload constructor and store a `const char *` always. This avoids copying but obviously doesn't work if you sometimes need to change the pointed-to characters
3. just write different mutable-string and immutable-string classes

If it helps, consider this:

```
template <typename T> struct test {
    T* p_;
    test(T *p) : p_(p) {}
};
template <typename T> test<T> mktest(T *p) { return {p}; }
```

and note that

```
const char *ccp = "immutable characters in a string literal";
char *cp = strdup(ccp);
auto a = mktest(ccp);
auto b = mktest(cp);
```

gives `a` the type `test<const char>`, and `b` the type `test<char>` and that these types are not the same, are not convertible, and are no more closely related in the language than to `test<T>` for any other type `T`.

Answer (score 4):

**A note:** this is a long answer for a use case that might be a bad design. Yet, the reason and the main focus for the long answer is:

- to show and explain what is ***not possible***
- to present a way in which one can make the compiler decide **based on the constness of a parameter** whether to create a *holding const object* and to preserve this information even if the object is passed on. Which is very close to the OP request.

---

As explained in other answers, you can have two constructors, one for `const` parameter and the other for `non-const`, but both constructors would just create an object that can be either `const` or `non-const`. So this doesn't help.

Another approach could be to have a ***factory method*** that would create either a const object or a non-const, according to the constness of the parameter. Though this may sound promising it would not allow to preserve the semantics of the difference between the two, as shown in the following pseudo code:

```
// creating an object holding a const, using the factory method `create`:
const MyClass const_holder  = create(const_param);

// however you cannot prevent this:
MyClass non_const_holder = create(const_param);
```

The factory would create in the second case above a *const* object that would be copied or moved (or just created directly as non_const_obj with copy elision, since C++17 as mandatory copy elision). You cannot do anything to avoid the second case unless you delete copy and move, in which case the first case wouldn't work also and the all thing collapses.

So, without creating actually two different types it is impossible to preserve the information of which constructor was used and to avoid assignment of an object created with const param into an object that doesn't.

However, there is no real need to bother the user with the fact that there are two classes, with a proper template implementation the user can have simple code that gives the feeling that there is only one class in the game, something like:

```
// creating a const holder with a factory method
// the type would *remember* that it is holding a const resource
// and can act accordingly
auto const_holder = create(const_param);

// and you can also create a non const holder with the same factory
auto non_const_holder = create(param);
```

These operations would be allowed:

```
// (a) calling a non const method on the content of the non const holder
non_const_holder->non_const_method();

// (b) assigning a non const holder into a const holder object
//     -- same as assigning char* to const char*
const_holder = non_const_holder;
```

These operations would NOT be allowed:

```
// (a) calling a non const method on the content of a const holder
const_holder->non_const_method(); // should be compilation error

// (b) assigning a const holder into a non const holder object
//     -- same as one cannot assign const char* to char*
non_const_holder = const_holder; // should be compilation error
```

**In a way, this is very similar to the idea of [propagate_const](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const)...**

The code would have a factory method:

```
template<class T>
Pointer<T> create(T* t) {
    return Pointer<T>::create(t);
}
```

And two implementations for the template class Pointer.

base template:

```
template<class T>
class Pointer {
    T* ptr;
    Pointer(T* p) : ptr(p) {}
    friend class Pointer<const T>;
public:
    // factory method
    static Pointer create(T* p) {
        return p;
    }
    operator T*() { return ptr; }
    operator const T*() const { return ptr; }
};
```

and a specialized one for the const version:

```
template<class T>
class Pointer<const T> {
    const T* ptr;
    Pointer(const T* p) : ptr(p) {}
public:
    Pointer(const Pointer<T>& other) {
        ptr = other.ptr;
    }
    // factory method
    static const Pointer create(const T* p) {
        return p; 
    }
    operator const T*() { return ptr; }
    operator const T*() const { return ptr; }
};
```

The main would look like:

```
int main() {
    char str[] = "hello";
    const char* const_str = "hello";
    // non-const - good!
    auto s1 = create(str);
    // const holding non-const - ok!
    const auto s2 = create(str);
    // non-const that holds const - good!
    auto s3 = create(const_str);
    // also possible: const holding const
    const auto s4 = create(const_str);

    s1[4] = '!'; // OK
    // s2[0] = '#'; // obviously doesn't compile - s2 is const
    // s3[0] = '@'; // doesn't compile - which is good - s3 holds const!
    // s4[0] = 'E'; // obviously doesn't compile - s4 is const
    // avoids assignment of s3 that holds a const into s1 that holds a non-const
    // s1 = s3; // <= doesn't compile - good!
    s3 = s1; // allows assignment of `holding-non-const` into `holding-const`
    s3 = s2; // allows assignment of `holding-non-const` into `holding-const`
    s3 = s4; // allows assignment of `holding-const` into `holding-const`
}
```

Code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4729be904215e4b2

Answer (score 2):

The problem you experience goes a bit deeper. It's an indication of a design issue.

You would like to expose only part of the API. You say that for a `const` object you will call only `const` methods and for `non-const` you can do anything. But this is problematic.

Either you accept `const` object strip it from `const` qualifier, and won't call non-const methods by a silent contract. Or, you need to limit methods, which makes a different object - type-wise.

C# library does it by providing a limited interface which wraps around original object and exposes only `const` methods. Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    void f1() const {cout << "foo\n"; }
    void f2() {cout << "bar\n"; }
};

struct readonlyA {
    readonlyA(const A& a) : _a(a) {};
    void f1() const {_a.f1();};
private:
    const A& _a;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    readonlyA roA(a);
    a.f2();
    roA.f1();
    roA.f2(); // error
    return 0;
}
```

It's basically a read-only proxy.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @luk32. I will need to think very well before making such split in my framework since a lot of things depend on it, but, of course it is probably a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does not care about what you actually do with the object at runtime.

Const works because the compiler will forbid certain things at compile time that could potentially change the object. This might be over-restrictive in certain situations, as the compiler often does not have the full picture of what's going on in the program.

Take for example the invocation a non-const member function on a const object: Even if the member function does not actually change the object's state, the compiler will still forbid it because the non-const function *could* potentially change the object.

Similar in your example: Even though you don't change the member for that particular const instance of the class, there could be other non-const instances of the same class somewhere, which is why it will refuse construct *any* instance of the class from a const object.

If you want a class that is guaranteed to leave its members unchanged, that would be a *different type*:

```
class test
{
public:
    test( char *arg )
    :   _arg( arg )
    {}  
    char *_arg;
};

class immutable_test
{
public:
    immutable_test(char const* arg)
        :_arg(arg)
    {}

    char const* _arg;
};

int main( )
{
    char *txt1       = "Text one";  // Ignore this warning.
    const char *txt2 = "Text two";

    test           t1( txt1 );
    immutable_test t2( txt2 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done. Just because the object is const, it doesn't mean that it guarantees the `char*` won't be used to modify its value. The constructor can mutate the argument, and code outside the class can modify its content if it is exposed. Consider the following example.

```
struct Test {
    char* buffer;

    Test(char* buffer):
        buffer(buffer)
    {
        buffer[0] = 'a';
    }

    char* get() const {
        return buffer;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::string s{ "sample text" };

    const Test t(s.data());

    t.get()[1] = 'b';
    t.buffer[2] = 'c';

    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

The above prints `abcple text`, even though `t` is const. Even though it never modifies its members, it does change the pointed-to string and it allows outside code to modify it, too. This is why `const` objects cannot accept `const char*` arguments to initialize their `char*` members.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is preventing you from carelessly discarding the constness...

```
    class test
    {
         public:
            test(const char *arg)
            : _arg(arg)
         {}
         const char *_arg;
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Robert Watkins but unfortunatelly it doesn't help. If I do `const` my `_arg` it will be forever `const` and my `non-const` methods can't be used.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.
Look at the example below (object `myclass2`) to learn how a const object does not necessarily provide the protection that you need!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cassert>

class MyClass
{
  public:
    MyClass(char * str1, size_t size1) : str{str1}, size{size1}
    {
    }
    char * capitalizeFirstChar()
    {
        *str = std::toupper(*str);
        return str;
    }
    char nthChar(size_t n) const
    {
        assert(n < size);
        return str[n];
    }

    char * str;
    size_t size;
};


int main()
{
    {
        static char str1[] = "abc";
        MyClass myclass1(str1, sizeof(str1) / sizeof(*str1));

        myclass1.capitalizeFirstChar();
        std::cout << myclass1.nthChar(0) << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "----------------------" << std::endl;
    {
        static const char str2[] = "abc";
        //             UGLY!!! const_cast
        const MyClass myclass2(const_cast<char *>(str2), sizeof(str2) / sizeof(*str2));

        // myclass2.capitalizeFirstChar();        // commented: will not compile

        std::cout << myclass2.nthChar(0) << std::endl;

        char c = 'x';
        // myclass2.str = &c;                     // commented: will not compile
                                                  // The const myclass2, does not
                                                  // allow modification of it's members

        myclass2.str[0] = 'Z';  // WILL COMPILE (!!) and should cause a segfault
                                // The const myclass2, CANNOT PROTECT THE OBJECT POINTED TO by str
                                // Reason: the member in MyClass is 
                                //                      char *str  
                                //         not 
                                //                const char *str

        std::cout << myclass2.nthChar(0) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Ok, the `str` member issue is actually best solved, by just making the members private.

But what about that ugly `const_cast`?
One way of solving this is splitting into a Const baseclass, and deriving for non-const behaviour (working with const-casts). Like this perhaps:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cassert>

class MyClassConst
{
  public:
    MyClassConst(const char * str1, size_t size1) : str{str1}, size{size1}
    {
    }
    char nthChar(size_t n) const
    {
        assert(n < size);
        return str[n];
    }

    const char * str;
    size_t size;
};

class MyClass : public MyClassConst
{
  public:
    MyClass(char * str1, size_t size1) : MyClassConst{const_cast<const char *>(str1), size1}
    {
    }
    char * capitalizeFirstChar()
    {
        char * cp = const_cast<char *>(str);
        *cp       = std::toupper(*cp);
        return cp;
    }
};


int main()
{
    {
        static char str1[] = "abc";
        MyClass myclass1(str1, sizeof(str1) / sizeof(*str1));
        myclass1.capitalizeFirstChar();
        std::cout << myclass1.nthChar(0) << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "----------------------" << std::endl;
    {
        static const char str2[] = "abc";
        //             NICE: no more const_cast
        const MyClassConst myclass2(str2, sizeof(str2) / sizeof(*str2));

        // a.capitalizeFirstChar();               // commented: will not compile

        std::cout << myclass2.nthChar(0) << std::endl;

        char c = 'x';
        // myclass2.str = &c;                     // commented: will not compile
                                                  // The const myclass2, does not
                                                  // allow modification of it's members

        // myclass2.str[0] = 'Z';                 // commented: will not compile

        std::cout << myclass2.nthChar(0) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Is it worth it? Depends.
One is kindof trading the const-cast outside of the class... for const-cast **inside** the class. So maby for library code (including ugly internals, and static code analysis exceptions), with clean outside usage, it's a match...