# Could passing "this" pointer in constructor possibly discard qualifiers and lead to undefined behaviour

Tags: c++

I have this simple mechanism for subscribing and sending messages.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Messager;
struct Subscriber
{
    Subscriber(Messager& messager);
    void call() // This (non-const) version of the method is called
    {
        i = 10;
        std::cout << "Non-const " << i << '\n';
    }
    void call() const
    {
        std::cout << "Const\n";
    }
private:
    int i = 0;
};

struct Messager
{
    // This (non-const) version of the method is called
    void subscribe(Subscriber& subscriber)
    {
        callback = [&subscriber]
        {
            subscriber.call();
        };
    }
    
    // Expected behaviour is that this (const-qualified) version would be called
    void subscribe(const Subscriber& subscriber)
    {
        callback = [&subscriber]
        {
            subscriber.call();
        };
    }

    void notify()
    {
        callback();
    }
    std::function<void()> callback;
};

Subscriber::Subscriber(Messager& messager)
{
    messager.subscribe(*this);
}

int main()
{
    Messager messager;
    const Subscriber s{messager};
    messager.notify();
}
```

My question is if passing `this` pointer in the `Subsriber's` constructor to the `Messager::subscribe` method, can lead to undefined behaviour (as it appears that there is mutation of state in a const object) when `Messager::notify` is called?

If so, what can be done about that or how could one make the compiler enforce that it's is not allowed?

Comment: In `messager.subscribe(*this)` the object on which the method is called is *nonconst* object so the nonconst method is called. Also refer to [The object isn't const during construction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49151864/12002570)

Comment: You need to add `const` to argument of `subscribe()` function. And if you need both const and non-const variants, then you can use either `const_cast()` or `std::as_const()` when calling it from constructor.

Comment: See [The object isn't const during construction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49151864/12002570)

Comment: @Peter There **is** UB in call `messager.notify();`. *" Modifying a const object through a non-const access path results in undefined behavior."*

Comment: @Peter `i = 10;` in `Subscriber::call()` is the modification of a const object is it not?

Comment: Apologies. My answer (deleted) missed a trick.  The local variable `s` is declared `const` and so attempting to modify it is undefined behaviour. There's a logical issue that `const` objects aren't `const` during construction or destruction and this code wriggles through that hole.