# How to init a constant std::array?

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

```
#include <array>
struct A
{
    A(char value, char another);
    const std::array<char, 42> something;  // how to init?
}
```

Considered approaches:

- a `const_cast` is always dangerous and often UB
- the docs list the only ctor as taking an aggregate parameter - what I want to do is accept some other parameter and initialize the constant
- removing the constness is ... undesirable. The whole semantics are "create this; it will never need to change"
- using `std::string` worries me as inefficient and this is an embedded device
- `std::experimental::make_array` looks promising but not standard yet
- an init list in the ctor seems promising but how?

Can it be done and how?

Comment: Not sure what is wrong with the usual way, using an initialiser list. `A(char value) : a{{value}} {}`

Comment: [The object isn't const during construction, or the constructor wouldn't be able to initialize the object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60556293/12002570)

Comment: @john this solves it. Sorry for bothering everyone: my brain is non-existent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the member initialization list of `A`'s constructor to initialize the array, eg:

```
A::A(char value) : arr{value} {}
```

---

**UPDATE**: you edited your question after I posted this answer.

In your original code, the constructor took a single `char`, and the `array` held 1 `char`, so it was possible to fully initialize the `array` with that `char`.

Now, in your new code, the constructor takes 2 `char`s, but the `array` holds 42 `char`s, so the only way to fully initialize the `array` with any values other than zeros requires using a helper function that returns a filled `array`, eg:

```
std::array<char, 42> makeArr(char value) {
    std::array<char, 42> temp;
    temp.fill(value);
    return temp;
}

A::A(char value, char another) : arr{makeArr(value)} {}
```

Comment: Here is the dupe covering this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14495926/12002570

Comment: makeArr can be constexpr (without change in C++20, replace fill with for loop pre C++20)